# What is the best approach to design database with external users, groups and permissions?

Tags: database, database-design, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, auth0

We are removing User, User Group and Permission models from our backend in favor of Auth0.
Our first idea was to just delete User, Group and Permission tables from DB and replace related foreign keys with varchar field. In this field we would then enter IDs that we get from Auth0 in JWT (pointing to something not present in our DB).

Is this good approach? I somehow feel that there must be more "relational" way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally OAuth will not do all of the permission checks for you. Instead it gives you general mechanisms to sign the user in and issue + validate tokens.

In most real world architectures you also need to manage a second level of authorization in your back end - using domain specific user data for roles, permissions etc.

A couple of write ups of mine may help:

- [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/)
- [API Authorization](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)

Comment: Yes, we are aware that we need to implement permission checks. But we will get permission list in token (list of groups user belongs to with list of permissions for each group). This way we don't actually need permissions and group in our db

Comment: Ok - that can work perfectly fine in some setups. If you have multiple APIs with different groups / permissions it can get difficult to scale though, since different APIs often need to share the same access token policy. Whenever you change permissions for API 1 you will need to also roll out changes to Auth0 permission data. And in some scenarios the changes for API 1 can conflict with API 2.

Comment: In terms of database fields I would keep at least a small users table in your back end - that uses a database surrogate primary key. Also consider adding the token's user id to the schema as a unique constraint. Given an access token you will then be able to look up the user's personalised data. My user data management page above explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 Community Manager Dan here,

In this scenario you may be able to leverage the [RBAC](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/rbac) to replace your existing users/groups/permissions setup.

You would register a user's roles and the associated permissions of each role in the Auth0 dashboard or programmatically via the management API. Then you can setup a rule to [add user roles to the token](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/sample-use-cases-rules#add-user-roles-to-tokens).

To connect this user to your existing user data store you can store the Auth0 id, similarly to how you have described.

This allows you to lookup the user when the token is received, and to associate any permissions or roles the user has. You can make roles API-specific by adding a prefix to the role, or have roles be general depending on your needs.

Comment: We started to implement it like that few days ago. We have one problem - we need to be able to propagate changes in permissions almost immediately. So when admin changes permission of some user our backend services must be aware of that using token. What do you recommend in this case? I assume that very short token validity is not way to go

Comment: I see. The need for immediate consistency with your admin changes will mean that having the permissions info in the token is likely not a good route. You are going to need to store that information in your DB, and associate it with the user ID, similar to what you have described. I have seen short lived tokens used for this type of access control data changes, but it doesn't sound like a solution to your case if you need it to be nearly immediate.